# How to measure the air pressure of a pipe without having water resistant sensor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pressure

I'm having a question regarding the sensors and the techniques in fluid mechanics. Since my skills are amazing in this field, here I'm asking you questions xD

I want to measure the air pressure of this tube/pipe (P1,P2,P3). This pipe will be flushed with water and then with compressed air.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In principle, it should be just pressure sensor in each pipe and problem solved!

Comment: Perhaps you could use a small extension tube with a loop in it... As the would be no flow in that tube then water should not get to the pressure sensor - but you will have to make sure you will get the required accuracy.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Much appreciated.

Can you please be more specific? why there will be no flow? and by loop you mean circular tube?

I'll try to drow your idea and post it so you can check if it's the same as you mean.

Comment: if you block one end of the tube with the pressure sensor then there will be no moving fluid therefore no flow...

Comment: Just to make sure, this is what you mean by the loop and the pressure sensor? 
http://2.1m.yt/CHGisly.jpg

Comment: I would suggest a complete loop would be better with the end continuing above so any fluid won't condense down onto the sensor.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure if I understood the continuing end part. " I really lack experience in this field, that's why I'm trying to ask too many questions, I'm sorry". 

Can you please drow it for me? or more details as I really do need to undertstand it.

Comment: What are the orders of pressure measured? For low pressures, isolating the sensor with a membrane would suffice. For high pressures, just measure the stress of the pipe.

Comment: What's so special about the water sensitive pressure transducer that you would use it over one suited to the environment?

Comment: I have read about the membrane layers online , but coudln't find any detailed information about this technique!  I have low pressure

The reason I want them is to lower the price

Comment: @Manaf: You won't read about them in simple applications because they are *too* simple to write about. A T-connector creates a branch in the pipe for the pressure sensor. A short piece of pipe is connected to the T-connector, with a membrane jammed between the pipe and T-connector - made out of any material that will withstand the environment and not distort the readings much. Plastic foil (like shrink-wrap) for very low pressures, rubber for higher. May be glued onto a  washer to be put between the segments, preferably with some slack. Put your sensor into the pipe segment, seal it off.

Comment: ...the membrane moves with the pressure, being slack obstructs it very little, but prevents media from mixing; pressure is transferred, gas/liquid - not.

Comment: An even cheaper method: seal the pressure sensor in a rubber balloon, not inflated but not entirely empty - loose, slack but not squished.

Comment: @SF.: sorry for the late reply, I just noticed that someone replied :(
I'll check this mthode. It seems pretty easy. Just cover the Pressre probe with a rubber balloon ( as a conclusion of what you said). Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Perhaps you could use a small extension tube with a loop in it... Mounted vertically not horizontally, so as to act as a liquid trap... As the would be no flow in that tube then water should not get to the pressure sensor - but you will have to make sure you will get the required accuracy. Fit the pressure sensor to the top end.

Comment: Ok thank you but from my point of view, I don't think this will work. As there will be drops of water when the air is flushed inside the tube, so the water (drops) will reach the sensor. Or if the tube (P1) is blocked, the water will go back to the sesnor and damage it. 
Thank you for taking the time to reply thou

Comment: if you connect this to your 4way junction so it is vertical then how will the drops reach the sensor? I don't think you have followed the idea. I did this with a 2m long pipe to attach a pressure sensor that was only rated to 100 degrees C to  steam pipe with superheated steam in it (over 170 degrees C) and got the pressure with no damage to the sensor.

Comment: Ok I think this is what you mean? 

I hope that I fully understood it now as I'm trying my best to do so.

http://4.1m.yt/2TGEk0x.jpg

Comment: Dear Mike, 
can you please confirm? as it is really important to me.

Comment: @Manaf if the loop is perpendicular to the other pipes then it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response Sir! 

I think I'll try to add valves to (P1,P2,P3) and then measure the pressure of each using this technique (eventhough I can't think of anything to make it perpendicular to all pipes P1,P2,P3 other than this picture I draw). 
If the results were not very accurate, I'll try to add the loop to each Pipe and see if it differs. 

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question and help me!

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this. The simplest is to use a standard pressure gauge on a vertical pipe sticking out of your pipes. It will be exposed to minimal water vapour and unless you are using a fancy delicate gauge you will be fine. Below is something I found on how gauges work and why you will be fine if water does get into the gauge:

---

Pressure gauges commonly use a Bourdon tube. Bourdon tubes are a coiled metal tube and as the pressure increases, it forces the coil straight which then moves the needle. (think blowing a party horn, which causes it to unroll) The type of fluid (water/air) makes no difference to the tube, only the pressure exerted against the tube does. And since most of the tubes are made from bronze, copper or stainless water will not corrode it any faster than moist air from the compressor.

In all said, the air compressor gauge will most likely work without any issues.

But if you really want to get a water gauge, go to a pool supply store. They have pressure gauges for filters that are designed for water and use a 1/4 npt. They also have a nifty little ring on the outside where you can mark your normal pressure so it is easy to see if your pressure is low or high.
[LINK](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/74354/can-i-use-a-gauge-designed-for-measuring-air-pressure-to-measure-water-pressure)

---

Pipelines that are drained and filled often have surges of water that can damage piping and gauges by what is called 'water hammer' when a slug of water is propelled at high velocity by air behind it. If your pipe is designed to fill and drain it should be able to handle these surges but I would monitor the gauge for a few cycles to ensure excessive pressures are not observed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. 

Hmmm I found this a little bit confusing. As I wanted to change the one I have ( water resistant) to a cheaper one (not water resistant).
According to your reply, I can use both. But this goes to the pressure gauge not to the pressure transimitter (electrical) " this is what I have "

Comment: @Manaf There are many pressure transmitters that work with the bourdon tubes that will not be damaged by water. The electronics should be water resistant if they are located where they could be splashed, but they will not be damaged by water on the inside. The water resistance of the one you have is probably splash resistant on the outside, they tend to be more expensive due to the nema certification and manufacturing processes needed. If your pipes are in a safe splash free area and the gauge only exposed to water on the inside of the pipe you should be fine to use the cheaper one.

Comment: I think you got my point wrong. I don't want to measure the water pressure. I want to measure the air pressure only that's why I don't want to buy a water resistant pressure sensor.

Comment: It will measure both and should not be bothered by the water.